# How to read GDX file with Python,without GAMS

Tags: python, file

There is a way to read GDX(GAMS Data eXchange ) files, without need of GAMS???
There is a way to read via GAMS and its api for Python,but I haven't GAMS in my pc.
Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way, but:

To use the api the free/demo version is enough! If you can not install it on your machine due to missing privileges, etc... You can also copy the installation from another machine. You might need to tell the api-implementation then where to find your gams "installation".

Answer (score 0):

I know there is R package which talks with GAMS. You might want to try it if you have R installed on you PC. The package and function you are looking for is GDXRRW and rgdx. See detail and examples here:
https://support.gams.com/gdxrrw:interfacing_gams_and_r